# Wpf change size of data inside gridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hello i have data in a gridView and i want to change the size of the data:
i mean i want to resize the data who comes from a list in c#

code:

```
<Window x:Class="DadBussines.PL.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1600">
<Grid>

    <Label Content="product name" FontSize="25" Margin="705,121,652.6,590.4"/>
    <TextBox Name="name_textBox" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="599,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" AllowDrop="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" TextChanged="name_textBox_TextChanged" />


    <Button Content="add product" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Click="Button_Click_Add_Product"/>
    <Button Content="delete product" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Click="Button_Click_Delete_Product"/>
    <Button Content="add amount" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="304,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Click="Button_Click_Add_Amount"/>
    <Button Content="delete amount" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="461,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Click="Button_Click_Remove_Amount"/>
    <Button Content="change price" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="629,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Click="Button_Click_Change_Price" />
    <Label Content="money in staff" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1388,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
    <Label Name="sumOfMoney_label" Content="" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1185,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"/>

    <ListView Margin="10,288,10,10" Name="products_ListView"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="index" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="name product" Width="312" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="price product" Width="312" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="amount product in cartons" Width="312" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding amount}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="amount product inside cartons" Width="312" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding amount_in_box}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="product type" Width="312" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding catagory}" />


            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: try asking a question

Comment: i ask how do i change the size of the data inside a gridView

Comment: resize what data?  are you asking to resize the listview control?  if so, you will want to start with getting rid of all these margins so the controls can do their thing.   look up grids, and make some columns and rows, and assign each control to them etc.

Comment: @liron what do you mean by _i want to resize the data_? What data do you want resize? What do you mean by data?

Comment: i pull out data(name,price,amount,productType) from database and i present the data in gridView now the font of this data is very small and i want to make the font bigger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the output of each gridviewcolumn you need to set the celltemplate property of the column to something.

Take a look at the sample on MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx